# Cannot execute FastAPI client code in Spyder

Tags: python, python-asyncio, spyder, fastapi, uvicorn

While trying to develop a FastAPI client in Spyder environment, one cannot start the execution.

The code fails and raises:

RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop
Minimum code to be executed:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
import uvicorn

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, port=8080, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: Found a solution in the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50243393/runtimeerror-this-event-loop-is-already-running-debugging-aiohttp-asyncio-a .

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) If you want to run applications that use `asyncio` in Spyder, you need to install a package called `nest_asyncio` first and then run the following code in the IPython console before running your code:

```
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()
```

*Note*: You only need to run that code once.