# Python Discord Bot: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop

Tags: python, discord.py, spyder

I have been trying to build a discord bot using Python. Unfortunately, I have came across this error in the code which always seem to come up when I run the code.

Here is my error message:

```
runfile('D:/Isaac Khong/Personal and School/Personal/programming/python/Discord Bots/iK10 Official/ik10-discordbot.py', wdir='D:/Isaac Khong/Personal and School/Personal/programming/python/Discord Bots/iK10 Official')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:\Isaac Khong\Personal and School\Personal\programming\python\Discord Bots\iK10 Official\ik10-discordbot.py", line 56, in <module>
    client.run('4e17e1549ce6dc2eff051db897ffb86d90514ac6dbbb68e20d9074af4aea9559')

  File "C:\Users\isaac\Anacoonda_New\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 860, in run
    asyncio.run(runner())

  File "C:\Users\isaac\Anacoonda_New\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 33, in run
    raise RuntimeError(

RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop
```

This is the code, using the example at https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html:

```
import discord

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')

client.run('My Client ID Here (in a string)')
```

I have also tried my own code here, which comes up with the same error pointing to the line "client.run("Client ID Here")":

```
import discord



TOKEN = '1081845655909187594'
GUILD = "iK10 Community"
intents = discord.Intents.default()
client = discord.Client(intents = intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    for guild in client.guilds:
        if guild.name == GUILD:
            break

    print(
        f'{client.user} is connected to the following guild:\n'
        f'{guild.name}(id: {guild.id})'
    )

client.run(TOKEN)
```

I am using Spyder Anaconda. This is my version of discord.py:

```
(base) C:\Users\isaac>pip show discord.py
Name: discord.py
Version: 2.2.2
Summary: A Python wrapper for the Discord API
Home-page: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py
Author: Rapptz
Author-email:
License: MIT
Location: c:\users\isaac\anacoonda_new\lib\site-packages
Requires: aiohttp
Required-by:
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hey there, you seem to be mistaking your bot token with client id. To run your bot, you should use your bot token. As for the error, I don't see `asyncio.run(runner())` in the code you provided which is referenced in the error.

Comment: @Raymus That is because `asyncio.run(runner())` is from line 860 of the [client.py](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/discord/client.py#L860) file in `discord.py`'s source folder. Which is shown in the traceback.

Comment: And for the question, the traceback is saying that the `client.run` method that caused the error is being called from line 56 of the file `ik10-discordbot.py`, and the code that you provided doesn't seem to have that many lines, is it? Can you provide the full code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asyncio is having some trouble running many loops at once, like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55409641/asyncio-run-cannot-be-called-from-a-running-event-loop-when-using-jupyter-no)

It appears to be some problem with Spyder. Luckily, [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50243393/runtimeerror-this-event-loop-is-already-running-debugging-aiohttp-asyncio-a) fixes that problem by using `nest_asyncio`

Comment: Thanks! I think I can use another editor like VS Code or IDLE to solve this.